# Timer web app with apps script and Google sheets as backend problem pasting to the right sheet (newbie here)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

first time using stack overflow, I'm working on a simple webapp using apps script and Google sheet, its supposed to display a timer and record data to a sheet to use it as a database and even pick up where it left of for different users, however even resorting to chatgpt, I'm being unable to make it record the data to the right sheet, it creates a sheet with the users name but then pastes the data to the original sheet of the doc (sheet1)  I'm sure this is something silly that I'm missing like a single variable being called wrong but I've spent 6 hours across 2 days and I'm just not figuring it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

***Code.gs:***

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setTitle('Web App')
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  return html;
}


function getUserEmail() {
  var fullEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var localPart = fullEmail.split('@')[0];
  return localPart;
}

function getOrCreateUserSheet() {
  // Get the local part of the email
  var localPart = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split('@')[0];

  // Check if a sheet with that name exists
  var userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(localPart);

  // If the sheet does not exist, create it
  if (!userSheet) {
    userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(localPart);

    // Optionally, initialize the sheet with headers or other values
    userSheet.getRange("A1").setValue("Start Time");
    userSheet.getRange("B1").setValue("End Time");
    userSheet.getRange("C1").setValue("Task");
    userSheet.getRange("D1").setValue("Activity Ping");
    // Add more headers as needed
  }

  return userSheet;
}

function startTimer(mainTask, secondaryTask) {
  var localPart = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split('@')[0];
  var userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(localPart);
  var currentTime = new Date();
  
  // Find the first empty row in Column A (starting from row 12)
  var row = userSheet.getRange("A12:A").getValues().filter(String).length + 12;

  // Register the current date/time, main task, and secondary task
  userSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(currentTime);
  userSheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(mainTask);
  userSheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(secondaryTask);

  // Initialize the timer value in Column B
  userSheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue("00:00:00");

  // Set the activity ping and status
  userSheet.getRange("B6").setValue(currentTime);
  userSheet.getRange("C6").setValue("Online");

  // Return the row number for future updates
  return row;
}

function updateTimer(row, timerValue) {
  var userSheet = getOrCreateUserSheet();
  userSheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(timerValue);
}
```

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Web App</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #user-email {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            padding: 10px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #title, #announcements {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #buttons {
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .emoji-button {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        main {
            display: flex;
        }

        #left-sidebar, #right-sidebar {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }

        #center-section {
            flex: 3;
            padding: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #timer {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 32px;
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        #tasks {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #aaa;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #aaa;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script>



        function displayEmail() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(email) {
                document.getElementById('user-email').innerText = "Logged in as: " + email;
            }).getUserEmail();
        }

        // Call the function when the page loads
        window.onload = displayEmail;

        function initializeApp() {
          google.script.run.getOrCreateUserSheet();
          displayEmail();
        }

        // Call the function when the page loads
        window.onload = initializeApp;


      var timerInterval;

        function startTimerDisplay(row) {
          var timerElement = document.getElementById('timer-display');
          var startTime = new Date();
          timerElement.innerText = '00:00:00';

          // Clear any existing timer interval
          clearInterval(timerInterval);

          timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
            var elapsedTime = new Date() - startTime;
            var hours = Math.floor(elapsedTime / 3600000);
            var minutes = Math.floor((elapsedTime % 3600000) / 60000);
            var seconds = Math.floor((elapsedTime % 60000) / 1000);
            timerElement.innerText = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
                                    minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
                                    seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');

            // Call server-side code to update the timer value in the sheet every minute
            if (elapsedTime % 60000 === 0) {
              google.script.run.updateTimer(row, timerElement.innerText);
            }
          }, 1000);
        }

        document.getElementById('start-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
          // Get selected main task and secondary task (update this part based on your dropdown implementation)
          var mainTask = ''; // Retrieve from dropdown
          var secondaryTask = ''; // Retrieve from dropdown

          // Call server-side code to start the timer
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(startTimerDisplay).startTimer(mainTask, secondaryTask);
        });
        

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="user-email"></div>
    <header>
        <div id="title">App Title</div>
        <div id="announcements">Announcements</div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button class="emoji-button"></button> <!-- Points -->
            <button class="emoji-button">⚙️</button> <!-- Settings -->
            <!-- Additional buttons as needed -->
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="left-sidebar">
            <div class="placeholder">Links go here</div>
        </div>
        <div id="center-section">
            <div id="timer">
                <h1 id="timer-display">00:00:00</h1>
                <button id="start-button">Start</button>
                <button id="stop-button">Stop</button>
            </div>
            <div id="tasks">
                <select id="main-task-dropdown">
                    <!-- Main task options here -->
                </select>
                <select id="secondary-task-dropdown">
                    <!-- Secondary task options here -->
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-sidebar">
            <div class=">Forms go here</div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <!-- Optional footer content here -->
    </footer>
</body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <base target="_top">

    <style>

      #timerDisplay {

        font-size: 24px;

        font-weight: bold;

        margin: 20px 0;

      }

    </style>

    <script>

      let elapsedTime = 0;

      let isRunning = false;

      let timer;

      let userName = ""; 

      let userCategory = "";

      let userSubCategory = "";

      function formatTime(seconds) {

        let hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);

        let minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);

        seconds = seconds % 60;

        return `${String(hours).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(seconds).padStart(2, '0')}`;

      }

      function startTimer() {

        userCategory = document.getElementById("mainCategory").value;

        userSubCategory = document.getElementById("subCategory").value;

        if(userName.trim() === "") {

          alert("Loading user name. Please wait...");

          return;

        }

        if(!isRunning) {

          isRunning = true;

          timer = setInterval(() => {

            elapsedTime++;

            document.getElementById("timerDisplay").innerText = formatTime(elapsedTime);

            

            if (elapsedTime % 60 === 0) {

              google.script.run.updateTimeForUser(userName, userCategory, userSubCategory, elapsedTime);

            }

          }, 1000);

        }

      }

      function stopTimer() {

        clearInterval(timer);

        isRunning = false;

        google.script.run.updateTimeForUser(userName, userCategory, userSubCategory, elapsedTime);

      }

      function fetchTimeForUser() {

        userCategory = document.getElementById("mainCategory").value;

        userSubCategory = document.getElementById("subCategory").value;

        

        if(userName.trim() !== "") {

          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((time) => {

            elapsedTime = time;

            document.getElementById("timerDisplay").innerText = formatTime(elapsedTime);

          }).getTimeForUser(userName, userCategory, userSubCategory);

        }

      }

      function updateSubCategories() {

        var mainCategory = document.getElementById("mainCategory").value;

        var subCategorySelect = document.getElementById("subCategory");

        while (subCategorySelect.firstChild) {

          subCategorySelect.removeChild(subCategorySelect.firstChild);

        }

        let options = [];

        

        if (mainCategory === "Production") {

          options = ["Task1", "Task2", "Task3"];

        } else if (mainCategory === "Meeting") {

          options = ["Mandatory", "Optional"];

        } else if (mainCategory === "Learning") {

          options = ["Optional1", "Optional2"];

        }

        options.forEach((option) => {

          var opt = document.createElement('option');

          opt.value = option;

          opt.innerHTML = option;

          subCategorySelect.appendChild(opt);

        });

      }

      window.onload = function() {

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((name) => {

          userName = name;

          document.getElementById("userNameDisplay").innerText = "Name: " + name;

          fetchTimeForUser(); // Fetch time for user when name is loaded

        }).getActiveUser();

      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="userNameDisplay">Name: Loading...</div>

    <label>Category:</label>

    <select id="mainCategory" onchange="updateSubCategories(); fetchTimeForUser()">

      <option value="Production">Production</option>

      <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>

      <option value="Learning">Learning</option>

    </select>

    

    <label>Sub-Category:</label>

    <select id="subCategory">

      <option value="Task1">Task1</option>

      <option value="Task2">Task2</option>

      <option value="Task3">Task3</option>

    </select>

    

    <div id="timerDisplay">00:00:00</div>

    <button onclick="startTimer()">▶️</button>

    <button onclick="stopTimer()">⏹️</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

(Sorry if this looks terrible it's my first time and I'm doing it on mobile )

I was expecting to get a new sheet with the users name (local part of email) and to record the timers data to it, instead it is creating the new sheet with the right name but it's not recording data in it (it's all going to sheet1)

Comment: Your example is too complex.  Please provide a [mcve] that only focuses on the question you are asking and nothing else.